# CKRecord fetch return 1 record with empty RecordID

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord

[image]

Record from iCloud container is fetched, but there is no RecordID. At the same time in the panel on the site, I see it. I tried to extract the record from another application, I registered the necessary container in the settings - and it was extracted without error.

I do not understand - this is a bug Xcode? After all, the extraction code is identical in the second application, where everything works. And in the debugger at the bottom left you can see that RecordID is not empty.

Code:

```
privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        result(false)

    } else if results != nil, results!.count > 0, let me = results?[0] {
        let RN = (me[.recordID] as! CKRecord.ID).recordName
```

Error:

> Thread 2: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Variables View Console:

> _recordName    __NSCFString *  @"UA-kuka-2018-11-16 11:27:59"  0x00000001c0644320

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to get the `recordID` of a `CKRecord` is to use the `recordID` property.

Assuming `me` is actually a `CKRecord`:

```
let RN = me.recordID.recordName
```

Comment: But `recordID` isn't a key, it's a property of `CKRecord`.

Comment: This my code perfectly work in another app. This is confusing me.